# Solr Cloud 4.3 all instances return 404 result

Tags: solrcloud

I have a Solr Cloud with 1 external zookeeper where it has 2 collections and each collection is divided into 2 shards as follows:

solr#1 --> collection 1 - shard 1, collection 2 - shard 1

solr#2 --> collection 1 - shard 2, collection 2 - shard 2

Everything was running fine in Solr 4.2.1 until i upgraded(setup from scratch) to 4.3.1. All the setting were kept the same but now  any query to cloud returns 404 error. However all the shards do appear to Admin UI Solr Cloud section. Any reason why? Did anything got changed in 4.3 ?

```
`host:port/solr/collection1/select?q=*&wt=xml&indent=true`
```

Result: 
Server at host:port/collection1 returned non ok status:404, message:Not Found
`</str>
<int name="code">404</int>
</lst>
</response>`

Comment: can you add the logs while the solr was being initialized? that would make the problem clearer for everyone here

Comment: the problem is finally solved ... it looked to me the collections were not getting created properly ... btw i'm creating the collections via solr.xml and not through collections API ... 
For people who might encounter this issue in the near future: the trick was start Solr with classic mode first which initialize the collections properly then start SolrCloud ... this issue didnt exist before 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

For other people who encounter this..

I also had the same problem and it seems it was because the default value of `hostContext` in `solr.xml` should not be **empty** as before but now should be `"solr":` in `solr.xml`

Change

```
hostContext="${hostContext:}"
```

to

```
hostContext="${hostContext:solr}"
```

Comment: doskey, welcome to stack overflow, http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help will help you to present your solutions precisely.